# Как доработать скрипт?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть скрипт, который по кнопке открывает форму и скроллит на неё. Есть ещё две другие кнопки и две другие формы. Работают аналогично.

```
<style> 
/*Скрываем блок по ID*/ 
#rec126129438 { 
display:none; 
} 
</style> 
<script> 
$('[href = "#form1"]').click(function() { 
$('#rec126129438').slideToggle("slow", function() { 
if ($(this).is(":visible")) { 
$(document).animate({ 
scrollTop: $(this).offset().top 
}, "slow") 
} 
}); 
});
</script>
```

Что бы туда добавить, чтобы нажатие одной кнопки не только открывало соответствующую форму, но и скрывало остальные формы? Неважно, открыты они или нет. Т.е. всегда должно отображаться либо 0 форм (начальный вариант), либо одна.

Answer (score 0):

Скрыть можно с помощью перебора элементов по части имени id. В примере ниже используется 'rec':

```
$('*[id*=rec]:visible').hide();
```

Разместить код необходимо сразу после вызова обработки клика:

```
$('[href = "#form1"]').click(function() { 
   $('*[id*=rec]:visible').hide();
```

Но лучше будет создать для форм какой-то идентификатор отличный от id, например data-type="form" и скрывать по нему. Чтобы не скрыть элементы отличные от форм.

```js
$('div[data-type=form]').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="rec12654684" data-type="form">form1</div>
<div id="rec12654685" data-type="form">form2</div>
<div id="rec12654686" data-type="form">form3</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Не совсем окончательно помогло. Написал комментарий в теме

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо.
Почти работает. Вот код:

```
$('[href = "#form1"]').click(function() {
$('*[id*=rec126129438]:visible').hide();
$('*[id*=rec126130996]:visible').hide();
```

аналогично на других кнопках. на второй - формы 1 и 3, на третьей - 1 и 2.

Работает следующим образом:
нажал на первую кнопку - открылась первая форма, потом нажал на вторую кнопку - первая форма скрылась, открылась вторая. Всё ок. Но если нажать потом на первую кнопку опять, то первая форма не открывается.
Явно что-то ещё добавить надо, но что..

Comment: Тут не очень понятно какой код открывает первую и другие формы. Но вообще, она должна открываться через show(). Конечно лучше всего реализовать скрытие/отображение форм одной функцией, даже если дальше идут разные инструкции для каждой формы. Если поменяться id формы, то нужно будет менять его везде, или допустим будет необходимость добавить еще одну форму, это это нужно будет добавлять новую функцию и менять все существующие. А если там будет 10 форм, то это будет действительно проблема: все продумать и не забыть где что.

Comment: Если вы отображаете форму черезе slideToggle, то да, тут возможны проблемы. slideToggle и toggle они работают по-своему и нужно это учитывать.

Comment: ну если честно, у меня три отдельных кода добавлено. это скорее всего глупо и неправильно, но я вообще не разработчик. я инженер в другой области, делающий любительский сайт на тильде, и пытающийся немного разобраться, как работают скрипты, только и всего ) так что прошу не кидаться тапками.
три вот таких куска, как я запостил в стартовом сообщении.

Comment: Это понятно, но нужно полный код ) Отредактируйте в этом ответе выше код и добавьте все формы + отображение формы, я посмотрю что можно сделать. У меня 20 лет опыт)

Comment: Спасибо Вам за отзывчивость. Мне помогли в другом месте, всё работает и даже ещё добавили новые кнопки для скрытия форм. Скину код в отдельном комментарии

Answer (score 0):

Вот, что получилось.
Вот стили:

```
<style>
#rec126130993 {
display: none;
}

#rec126129438 {
display: none;
}

#rec126130996 {
display: none;
}
</style>
```

И сам скрипт:

```
<script>
setTimeout(function () {
$('a[href="#form1"], a[href="#form2"], a[href="#form3"]').off().on('click', function() {
var id = $(this).attr('href').substr(1);
var anchor = $('a[name="' + id + '"]');
var el = anchor.parent().next();
var form_ids = ['rec126130993', 'rec126129438', 'rec126130996'];
for (var i = 0; i < form_ids.length; i++) {
if (el.attr('id') != form_ids[i]) {
$('#' + form_ids[i]).hide();
}
}
$('a[href="#form1"], a[href="#form2"], a[href="#form3"]').html('Выбрать');
if (el.is(":visible")) {
el.hide();
$(this).html('Выбрать');
} else {
el.show();
$(this).html('Скрыть');
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: anchor.offset().top}, 1000);
}
return false;
});
}, 2000);
</script>
```